# How to redirect stderr and stdout inside a while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, stdout, stderr

I have a loop set up to search through a datafile and perform COMMANDS using each line of the datafile as parameters.  The PUBLISH parameter can have spaces so that's why I have it escaped differently.  I want to be able to output stderr and stdout for each iteration of the loop to a different logfile:

```
while read VARIABLE1 PUBLISH LOGFILENAME
do
/home/script_name  -switch $VARIABLE1 -switch2 \"$PUBLISH\" >> /log/$LOGFILENAME 2>&1
done < $INPUTFILE
```

The logfile LOOKS to get created - that is - I can see it when I do an ll and it appears to have size - but when I attempt to cat the file - I'm getting:

```
# ll logfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     3205 2014-10-15 12:52 logfile
# pg logfile 
pg: logfile: No such file or directory 
# cat logfile 
cat: logfile: No such file or directory 
# read -r logfile 
^C (ctrl-c'd after no display) 
# file logfile 
logfile: ERROR: cannot open `logfile' (No such file or directory)
```

The COMMANDS are running fine - but I cannot get the logfile created.  If I remove the redirect string (>> /log/$LOGFILENAME 2>&1) - the COMMAND output goes to the screen just fine.  I'm executing the script and reading the logfile as root - so permissions should not be an issue.

Comment: Under what unix user you're running this script?

Comment: `logfile` and `sync*/logfile` are not the same path.

Comment: Please modify your test commands in tje last fragment such that no relative pathnames, no wildcards and no aliases are used, and show the resulting output.

Comment: I presume `/log` exists?

Comment: If you can `ll` it, then there is no reason you can't `cat` it (other than permissions). If it has size (which it appears to), then it has contents. If `/home/script_name` is providing output, then it is going to `/log/$LOGFILENAME 2>&1` if `$LOGFILENAME` is defined. Since you are reading `LOGFILENAME`, the name is suspect. Dump it and confirm. Also use `read -r` to avoid problems with escapes that may exist if a newline is contained in `LOGFILENAME`.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with what you are saying that it SHOULD have contents (and LOOKS like it does).  But I can't get the file to display no matter what I try:

Comment: Wild guess: What do you have `ll` aliased to?  Will `sh -c 'ls -l'` or `/usr/bin/ls -l` give you the same output?

Comment: type ll
ll is aliased to `ls -alF'

Comment: Let me try again. Can you do `ls -l '/log/logfile'`? Can you do `cat '/log/logfile'`? (These exact commands, with quotes and slashes).

Comment: The commands come back exactly the same 'No such file or directory' as the commands above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to n.m. who got me on the right track. I changed the output filename to a hardcoded name and it worked - I was able to see the logfile and page it.  I went back and looked at the original $INPUTFILE and discovered that there was a SPACE after the varialble name in the LOGFILENAME variable.